# Ограничение label

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. на картинку.
Надо,чтобы `label` имел ограничения в размере от правой "стены". Надо растянуть `label`, а если вручную растянуть, то на разных устройствах будет выглядеть по-разному.

Comment: Хороший вопрос!

Comment: Не понятен вопрос в данной формулировке. Что за ограничения?

Comment: ограничения  - это constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы создаете `UI` в `InterfaceBuilder`, тогда используйте auto layout,  укажите, что правый край `label` должен всегда быть привязан к правому краю вашего `View`. Если же создаете label в коде, то укажите `autoresizingMask` c нужными Вам значениями.